# Freedom of interpretation

Tags: halacha, commentaries

On one side verses like Devarim 4:2 and 12:32 teach us not to add nor to subtract, on the other side there seem to be this freedom of interpretation regards doing the mitzvot. Ofcourse there are mitzvot that we as metzuveh can follow according to the literal words of what the Metzaveh, HaShem, commanded us. But there are also commandments  which seem to lack an explanation of how one needs to fulfill them. In such cases halacha comes in.

But how far can one stretch the freedom of interpretation? Where does this freedom ends, and what are it's boundries/limits?

When do these interpretations help us do His Will and when do these interpretations lead us away from doing His Will?

Comment: Do you mean unilateral interpretation, or are you even asking about the interpretations of the Talmud which are generally assumed to Torah Sheb'al Peh; the Oral tradition?

Comment: Are you asking whether entire enterprise of rabbinic Judaism is legitimate inasmuch as it frequently seems absent from or even contradictory with Scripture? If so, what sort of answers do you want? Answers from within rabbinic literature that themselves employ this method to explain away the seeming problems with their approach (somewhat circular), or what?

Comment: The principle of "lo bashamayim hi" clearly permits man to interpret the Torah.

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm not talking about halacha, talmud or oral tradition per se. When HaShem gives a mitzva and one reads about it he knows what HaShem commands him to do, but not always how to do it, so he has to 'figure it out on his own'. Ofcourse all the formentioned sources could provide a answer, most of the times even many, but there is always room for one own interpretation and a open space to fill. So how does anyone, wether a rabbi or just a average person, determine if his own interpretation is legit, fitting or in line with HaShems Will?

Comment: @Levi It looks like you are making some important clarifications, but I am still not sure of your intent. You say that you are not talking about halakha; Jewish law, but then discuss how to do the mitsvot; the classic realm of halakha. || Generally rabbinic sources which combine biblical interpretation with traditions are sufficient. Could you give an example of what you are referring to?

Comment: @mevaqesh no matter if one follows 'the words of the rabbi's' or one own interpretation it is still some form of halacha; in the literal sense of the word, the way one feels to behave or the way one should be walking in order to fulfill the mitzva; "The Way For Us To Go." I just didn't want to point to oral law alone, because even the oral law is interpretated by its readers/hearers. So in my point of view Halacha reaches further as oral law alone. Just to be clear: I don't reject oral law, I take it to the heart, but I think Halacha in it's definition goes way beyond what's written.

Comment: Don't know what you're taking about, but using terms like halakha in ways other than their common usage can confuse people.

Comment: @mevaqesh Ok so let's keep it with the actual halacha then, how far can one stretch those, what are the rules for making halacha?